# Помогите с файлами на С

Tags: c, файлы

У меня задача сформировать файл, содержащий информацию о 10 автолюбителях: фамилию, марку автомобиля, цвет, номер. Используя эти данные, предоставить информацию об автолюбителях, имеющих "Жигули" белого цвета, и их номер начинается с 45.
Я написал код, но он выдает ошибки, помогите исправить.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main ()
{   
    int n;
    int *pr = NULL;
    pr = (int*) malloc(100);
    int *m = NULL;
    m = (int*) malloc(100);
    int *k = NULL;
    k = (int*) malloc(100);
    int *no = NULL;
    no = (int*) malloc(100);
    FILE *A;    
    A=fopen("cars.txt","w");
    if (A!= NULL) {
for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
printf("Введіть кількість автолюбителів: ");
scanf("%i",&n); 

printf("Прізвище: ");
scanf("%s",&pr); 

printf("Марка: ");
scanf("%s",&m); 

printf("Колір: ");
scanf("%s",&k); 

printf("Номер: ");
scanf("%s",&no);

printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n",pr,m,k,no);
fprintf(A,"%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n",pr,m,k,no); 
}
}
fclose(A);

{
    A=fopen("car.txt","r+");
    if (A!= NULL) {
printf("Білі жигулі з номером, який починається на 45 :\n");
while (!feof(A))
        {
            fscanf(A,"%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n",&pr,&m,&k,&no);
            if ((int *strcmp(char *m=="zhyguly" &&
                *k=="bilyy"  &&
                *no(1,2)=="45"))
               {
                printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", pr, m, k, no);
                }
            
fclose(A);
return 0;
}
}
}
```

Comment: может не scanf, а fscanf?

Answer (score 2):

Ну, здесь

```
scanf(A,"%i\n%i\n%i\n%i\n",pr,m,k,no);
```

вы читаете из файла, и функция нужна соответствующая: `fscanf`

```
fscanf(A,"%i\n%i\n%i\n%i\n",pr,m,k,no);
```

Только вот сравнение в C так:

```
m="жигулi"
```

не делается. Это — присваивание! Но даже если вы и написали бы `==` — то это было бы сравнение *указателей*, а не строк. Для сравнения строк нужно использовать функцию `strcmp()`.

Еще:
int pr;
int m;
int k;
int no;
...
printf("Фамилия: ");
scanf("%i",&pr);

У вас фамилия — это просто целое число? Как и модель? и номер? Как я понимаю, вам нужно вводить строки...

Что вы хотите сказать выражением `no(1,2)` — при том, что `no` — это просто значение типа `int` — для меня загадка. Первые две цифры? Но это делается совсем не так...

**Update**

Примерно вот что вам нужно:

```
int main()
{   
    int n;
    char pr[60];
    char m[60];
    char k[60];
    int no;
    FILE *A = fopen("cars.txt","w");
    if (A!= NULL) {
        printf("Введiть кiлькiсть автолюбителiв: ");
        scanf("%i",&n);
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
            printf("Прiзвище: ");
            scanf("%s",pr);      // ТОЛЬКО ОДНО СЛОВО!!!!

            printf("Марка: ");
            scanf("%s",pr);      // ТОЛЬКО ОДНО СЛОВО!!!! Mersedes Benz нельзя!!!

            printf("Колiр: ");
            scanf("%s",k);       // ТОЛЬКО ОДНО СЛОВО!!!! Мокрый асфальт - нельзя!!!

            printf("Номер (чотиризначне число): ");
            scanf("%d",&no);

            printf("Введено: %s\n%s\n%s\n%d\n",pr,m,k,no);
            fprintf(A,"%s\n%s\n%s\n%d\n",pr,m,k,no);
        }
    }
    fclose(A);

    A = fopen("car.txt","r+");

    if (A!= NULL) {
        printf("Бiлi жигулi з номером, який починається на 45 :\n");
        while(fscanf(A,"%s\n%s\n%s\n%d\n",pr,m,k,&no) == 4)
        {
            if (strcmp(m,"zhyguly") == 0 &&
                strcmp(k,"bilyy") == 0  &&
                no/100 == 45)
            {
                printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%d\n", pr, m, k, no);
                break;
            }
        }
        fclose(A);
    }
}
```

Comment: no - это типа номер, мне нужно чтобы если первые 2 цыфры номера были 45, то владельци белых жигулей с такими номерами выводились в отдельный файл

Comment: да, мне нужно использовать строки

Comment: Какой вид имеет номер? Просто число? Сколько в нем знаков? Или это может быть `FN45789HY`, например? Без точной спецификации вводимых данных дать какой-то ответ сложно.

Comment: Ну так используйте строки. В С это массив `char`.

Comment: номер состоит из 4 цыфр

Comment: Простите, вы С изучали? Хоть немного? Или делаете это только сейчас? Просто у вас вопросы такие, что стоит посоветовать начать с чтения учебника...

Comment: простите, просто с текстами и строками беда

Comment: Посмотрите эту книгу: https://www.twirpx.com/file/1128882/ или вот это: http://cppstudio.com/cat/271/

Comment: можете хоть немного отредактировать код?

Comment: К чему эти эвфемизмы? Это называется — написать заново...

Comment: понял, хоть что-то правильно?

Comment: посмотрите теперь пожалуйста

Comment: Нет, память под строки должна быть выделена. Да и читать вы пытаетесь теперь не в `int`, а в указатели, а не по адресу, содержащемуся в указателе.

Comment: я постарался виделеть память под строки

Comment: можете мне хоть начало кода написать, чтобы я понял как делать потом

Comment: Ладно, смотрите. Дальше — сугубо самостоятельно.